# Add row Dynamically in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this table using `DataTable` in Flutter and I want to make a button that adds new row under the 2 initial lines .
How can I achieve this ?

```
DataTable(
        columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
              label: Flexible(
            child: Text("",
                maxLines: 5,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          )),
          DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text("Nom de l'article",
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          )),
          
        ],
        rows: <DataRow>[
          DataRow(
            cells: <DataCell>[
              DataCell(TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              )), DataCell(TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              )),          
            ],
          ),
          DataRow(
            cells: <DataCell>[
              DataCell(TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              )),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and store data there.
Next build rows of the variable content.

If you wish to edit the data use Statefull Widget or state management.

After converting to Statefull Widget:

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(
        () => rowData.add({'id': '103', 'title': 'NewItem', 'author': 'You'}),
      ),
      child: Text('Add new item'),
    )
```

Read on Flutter documentation its really nicely written: [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive)

also [datatable article](https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-datatable-widget-guide-displaying-data/)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final rowData = [
    {'id': '100', 'title': 'Flutter Basics', 'author': 'David John'},
    {'id': '102', 'title': 'Git and GitHub', 'author': 'Merlin Nick'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
            label: Flexible(
          child: Text("",
              maxLines: 5,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        )),
        DataColumn(
            label: Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Text("Nom de l'article",
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        )),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            )),
            DataCell(TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
        ...rowData
            .map((item) => DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('#' + item['id'].toString())),
                  DataCell(Text(item['title'] ?? '')),
                  DataCell(Text(item['author'] ?? '')),
                  DataCell(FlutterLogo())
                ]))
            .toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```